# Grouping in Reporting Services

Tags: reporting-services, hierarchy, ssrs-grouping

I am trying to display information from various fields on a per client basis. In some instances a client will have no entries in a column, sometimes they will have one or more. I don't want to end up with any duplicate rows.

I've tried various combinations of parent and child groupings but can't get it to look the way I want.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
E.EntCode AS [Member],
A.Reference AS [Fixed Assets],
C.Reference AS [Cash],
L.Reference AS [Loans]

FROM
dbo.CR_Entity AS E
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.CR_FixedAssets AS A ON E.EntCode = A.EntCode
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.CR_Cash AS C ON E.EntCode = C.EntCode
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.CR_Loans AS L ON E.EntCode = L.EntCode

WHERE E.Status = '0'
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you edit your question and show a sample of data as it is in your dataset query, preferably the data that would produce the results you have shown in your question.

Comment: I've done that, hopefully it is what you were after. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure you'll be able to do this. The way the data is structured there is no hierarchical grouping. The closest you could get it to set the hide duplicates property on each field but as you cannot merge vertically in a table this will mean you still get  empty rows. Unless there is some relationship between each table that is not visible here (e.g. between loans and assets) then I can't think of a way of doing this. Maybe someone else will have a better idea